# Configure Sonar for Delphi with sub-modules

Tags: delphi, ant, sonarqube

I can get Delphi analysis working on single projects, so the plugin works.
I can get Submodules analysis set up as per my previous question but no delphi analysis is performed.

refer to [Configuration of build.xml file for Sonar modules with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092659/configuration-of-build-xml-file-for-sonar-modules-with-ant) for reference.

If I include the (I believe) required delphi configuration in the master build file it only works if I include the sonar.sources line.

BUT, when I include that line it is attempting to analyse all delphi code and is ignorning the submodules.

How (assuming it can be done) do I configure this to work or do I have to run each project completely separately?

**Master Build File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name = "EXO" default = "sonar" basedir = "." xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
<echo>Root Project</echo>

<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="c:/ANT/lib" />
</taskdef>

<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000" />
<property name="sonar.modules" value="exonet6000/build.xml,CRM/build.xml" />

<target name="sonar">
    <sonar:sonar key="EXO.key" version="0.1">   
        <property key="sonar.sources" value="." />      
        <property key="sonar.language" value="delph" />
    </sonar:sonar>
</target>
</project>
```

**Sub Project Build File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="CRM" default="all" basedir=".">
    <echo>CRM Module</echo>

    <property name="sonar.language" value="delph" />
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="EXO:CRM" />
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="." /> 

    <target name="all" />
</project>
```

Comment: You should be trying to use the latest version of the Ant Task instead, this will help you. You can check the documentation at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task